CSS to highlight "nested" rows using th and varied rowspan attributes using the :has selector
I have been playing around with the :has selector to see if I am able to create a pure-css solution for highlighting rows in "tree" views using HTML table.  I've seen solutions using <tbody>, but that will only work for a single level of "nesting."  How do we handle multiple <th> elements in the same row, and across rows that have varying rowspan values?
I came up with something that works, but requires a selector for every possible value of rowspan that could appear in the table.  You can imagine if these tables are dynamically generated, this would not be a solution that could scale.
I wanted to see if anyone else has solved this problem using modern CSS, or could think of a way to iterate on this solution to not need to have a rule per rowspan value.


body {
  padding: 50px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

tr:hover th,
tr:hover td,
tr:has(th[rowspan]):has(~ tr:hover) th[rowspan] {
  background-color: aqua;
}

tr:has(th[rowspan="2"]):has(+ tr ~ tr:hover) th[rowspan="2"],
tr:has(th[rowspan="3"]):has(+ tr + tr ~ tr:hover) th[rowspan="3"],
tr:has(th[rowspan="4"]):has(+ tr + tr + tr ~ tr:hover) th[rowspan="4"],
tr:has(th[rowspan="5"]):has(+ tr + tr + tr + tr ~ tr:hover) th[rowspan="5"],
tr:has(th[rowspan="6"]):has(+ tr + tr + tr + tr + tr ~ tr:hover) th[rowspan="6"],
tr:has(th[rowspan="7"]):has(+ tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr ~ tr:hover) th[rowspan="7"],
tr:has(th[rowspan="8"]):has(+ tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr ~ tr:hover) th[rowspan="8"],
tr:has(th[rowspan="9"]):has(+ tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr ~ tr:hover) th[rowspan="9"] {
  background-color: inherit;
}
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="5"></th>
      <th rowspan="2"></th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="3"></th>
      <th rowspan="2"></th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="9"></th>
      <th rowspan="4"></th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2"></th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="5"></th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="3"></th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



I was able to reduce the duplicate selectors in code by using a LESS loop, but this still will generate over 10kb of CSS.  There has to be a better way to do this!
.nestedRowHighlight {
    // Sets the background color if this row has a th with a rowspan, and a sibling row is being hovered
    tr:has(th[rowspan]):has(~ tr:hover) th[rowspan] {
        background-color: @hoverColor;
    }

    .resetAfterSpan(1, ~"");
}

// Adds rules for each rowspan (up to 100) to cancel the th highlight if the row being hovered is passed the rowspan of the th
.resetAfterSpan(@rowSpan, @trSiblings) when (@rowSpan <= 100) {
    // Recursively generate the rule
    .resetAfterSpan((@rowSpan + 1),  ~"@{trSiblings} + tr");

    tr:has(th[rowspan="@{rowSpan}"]):has(@{trSiblings} ~ tr:hover) th[rowspan="@{rowSpan}"] {
        background-color: inherit;
    }
}

